# How to optimize mouseover function's current logic to improve performance

Tags: reactjs, highcharts, stock-highcharts

I have 2 series (lines) displayed as shown in demo. I can have up to 30 series (lines) in one go.

What is implemented is, as soon as I move the mouse, it should update the **current value** (for all series (lines) - remember I can have up to 30 series in one go) in the grid shown right below stock chart. It is working as expected.

Pls find working demo : https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-ts-qcsum9?file=stockchart%2Fstockchart.js,constants%2Fzoom-level.js,stockchart%2FchartOptions.js

**FYI**: You can focus on only **mouseOver** function rather than looking in to all other files as demo has so many files.

---

**Problem** : Problem related to performance

As I told you I can have up to 30 series (lines) in one go. In given demo, there are two series(lines) and when you select 30 days, you have to move your mouse **slowly** in other to see updated or current hovered value in the gird. If you move your mouse speedily, it will not update the value immediately (I think that is obvious).

But the problem is on each mouse move, I'm looping through all available lines multiple times and perform some logic. I know it is a bit complex logic as shown in below code snippet. It runs every time when mouse is moved for each hovered point for all the lines. This is very bad way of updating the current value.

I know this is not the correct implementation but I really have NO IDEA how to optimize it. Any help would be greatly appreciated.
Code: Select all

```
point: {
        events: {
          mouseOver: (e) => {
            const xAxisValue = e.target.x;
            const chart = e.target.series.chart;
            const series = chart.yAxis[0].series;
            const totalGridSeries = [...stockGrid];

            for (let i = 0; i < series.length; i++) {
              const name = series[i].name || series[i].name;
              const foundSeries = totalGridSeries.find(
                (x) => x.name === name
              );
              if (foundSeries) {
                if (xAxisValue) {
                  const foundPoint = series[i].points.find(
                    (t) => t.x === xAxisValue
                  );
                  if (foundPoint && foundPoint.y) {
                    foundSeries.currentValue = foundPoint.y;
                  } else {
                    foundSeries.currentValue = undefined;
                  }
                } else {
                  foundSeries.currentValue = undefined;
                }
              }
            }

            setStockGrid(totalGridSeries);
          },
        },
      }
```

Comment: About problem 1, I'm trying to reproduce and in both cases when I select a time range from select (7 days or 30 days) and then move the range navigator and squeeze it the column of the current value doesn't change.  Is this what you want to get so that when you move the navigator the current value is updated(it is the value of the range from to)?

Comment: @SebastianHajdus Thanks for reaching out. You are not able to see it as I resolved `Problem 1` by my self. I unknowingly updated the answer in the same link. Now I'm only worried about `problem 2`. In any scenario, it always works but as I'm using `for loop`, it is hitting the performance badly and I want to optimize it.

Comment: You can use the same link https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-ts-qcsum9?file=stockchart%2Fstockchart.js,constants%2Fzoom-level.js,stockchart%2FchartOptions.js and help me optimize mouseOver function code so it becomes performant when I have 10 to 30 lines in one go.

Comment: For optimization, [boost](https://api.highcharts.com/highstock/boost) module should help improve rendered many series. When it comes to code in mouseOver events, using a loop for look good is faster than forEach.